# Converting Yes/No field to string in MS Access Report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a field in my query, `[Metrics].[Aligned]`, which is `Yes/No`. I need it to show up on my report as one of two strings depending on if it is true or false. I have the following expression to do that:

`Alignment: CStr(IIf([Metrics].[Aligned],"Aligned Metrics","Non-Aligned Metrics"))`

But when I go to create a report from this query, it still shows up as a `Yes/No` checkbox. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look at this site to see how to Format yes/no fields on a Access DB/Reoprt

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/format-property-yes-no-data-type-HA001232749.aspx

Here is a tutorial on how to change the boxes to Text for your reports

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/formatting-yes-no-fields-in-access-reports